# Multiple nested integrals in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate nested integrals of the following form:

```
s_min = 0; 
s_max = lam;
t_min = 0; 
t_max = pi;
pmax =  @(x,y) y;
pmin = 0;
ymax = 1;   
ymin = @(x) x;
xmax = 1;
xmin = 0;

eqn = integral(@(x) x.*integral(@(y) (1/y).*integral(@(p) (exp(-arrayfun(@(p,x,y)integral2(@(s,t)myfun(s,t,p,x,y),s_min,s_max,t_min,t_max),p,x,y)./(k.*T))),pmin,pmax,'Arrayvalued',true),ymin,ymax,'Arrayvalued',true),xmin,xmax,'Arrayvalued',true)
```

However, I get the error:

> Error using integral (line 85)
>   A and B must be floating point scalars.

I thought by adding `'Arrayvalued'` for the single integrals and `arrayfun` for the double integral that this would not be a problem. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

The range arguments for `integral()` have to be numbers, but you are giving functions `pmax` and `ymin`. You need to evaluate them. I separated it into multiple lines to make it somewhat readable.

```
fa = @(p,x,y) @(s,t) myfun(s,t,p,x,y);
fb = @(p,x,y)integral2(fa(p,x,y),s_min,s_max,t_min,t_max);
fc = @(x,y) @(p) (exp(-arrayfun(fb,p,x,y)./(k.*T)));
fd = @(x)@(y) (1/y).*integral(fc(x,y),pmin,pmax(x,y),'Arrayvalued',true);
fe = @(x) x.*integral(fd(x),ymin(x),ymax,'Arrayvalued',true);
eqn = integral(fe,xmin,xmax,'Arrayvalued',true)
```

Implementing high-dimensional integration this way seems quite inefficient, it did not finish on my machine while writing this. You may have to implement your own integrator.

Comment: Hi janismac, thanks! Do you have any suggestions or references on how I might make my own integrator? Is it possible to do this with looped functions?

Comment: For a bounded function on a rectangular domain (aka hypercube) it would be realtively easy. But your function has a singularity `1/y`, this would require some sort of adaptive grid and error control. The math of that is beyond me.